# How can I find the limit of the series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac {(-1)^n 2^{-n} x^{2n+1}} {n!}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I find the limit of the series $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac {(-1)^n 2^{-n} x^{2n+1}} {n!}$$ where $x \in \mathbb R$ ?

I've tried telescoping and looking at $s_k$ (partial sum).

Comment: Do not multiply questions artificially, this one should have been added to your other one.

Answer (score 2):

Your terms are of the form

$$
x \cdot \frac{((-1/2) x^2)^n}{n!}
$$

What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT #$1$:**

$\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{x^n}{n!}=e^x$

---

**HINT #$2$:**

$\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^n2^{-n}x^{2n+1}}{n!}=x\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^n(\frac{1}{2})^n(x^2)^n}{n!}=x\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-\frac{1}{2}x^2)^n}{n!}$

---

**So just in case you didn't get the hints, the answer is $\displaystyle{xe^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}}$**

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the series $$e^{\dfrac{-x^2}{2}}=1-\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2!}\dfrac{x^4}{4}-\dfrac{1}{3!}\dfrac{x^6}{6}+...$$

Multipying $x$ through out you will get $$xe^{\dfrac{-x^2}{2}}=x-\dfrac{x^3}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2!}\dfrac{x^4}{4}-\dfrac{1}{3!}\dfrac{x^6}{6}+...$$